# Update Nested Object Property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have the following piece of code below:

```js
class Set {
  constructor() {
    console.log("New Set!");
  }

  get repsCompleted() {
    return this._repsCompleted;
  }

  set repsCompleted(value) {
    this._repsCompleted = value;
  }
}

class Exercise {
  constructor(name) {
    console.log(name);
    this.name = name;
  }

  get sets() {
    return [new Set(), new Set(), new Set()]
  }
}

let barbellSquat = new Exercise("Barbell Squat");
let updatedBarbellSquat = updateRepsCompleted(barbellSquat);

console.log(updatedBarbellSquat);

function updateRepsCompleted(exercise) {
  for (var i = 0; i < exercise.sets.length; i++) {
    exercise.sets[i].repsCompleted = 5;
  }

  return exercise;
}
```

I have a class exercises, which has a property sets, which is an array of objects of type Set.

So I create a new object off the Exercise class then pass the object to a function, whose purpose is to update the set objects and set the property "repsCompleted" to 5.

Then I console.log the exercise object, only to find that repsCompleted is undefined. I can't figure out why.

Here's a fiddle with the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/the_archer/a09tpr63/10/

Comment: Don't use `Set`, that's a built-in JavaScript type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a getter for `sets`.  A getter or setter is used every time the corresponding property is read or assigned, to allow you to customize the way that property works. The getter isn't only used the first time the property is accesssed.

So every time you use `exercise.sets` it creates a new array containing 3 empty `Set` objects. `sets` should be an ordinary property so you can retrieve the same value every time. You can initialize it in the constructor.

If you want to hide the `sets` property, like you did with `repsCompleted` in the `Set` class, you can use the same method: use a different name for the actual property, and define a getter and setter that accesses it. You can also initialize it lazily by checking whether the property is set yet.

```js
class Set {
  constructor() {
    console.log("New Set!");
  }

  get repsCompleted() {
    return this._repsCompleted;
  }

  set repsCompleted(value) {
    this._repsCompleted = value;
  }
}

class Exercise{
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this._sets = null;
  }
  
  get sets() {
    if (!this._sets) {
      this._sets = [new Set(), new Set(), new Set()];
    }
    return this._sets;
  }
  
  set sets(value) {
    this._sets = value;
  }
}

let barbellSquat = new Exercise("Barbell Squat");
let updatedBarbellSquat = updateRepsCompleted(barbellSquat);

console.log(updatedBarbellSquat);

function updateRepsCompleted(exercise) {
  for (var i = 0; i < exercise.sets.length; i++) {
    exercise.sets[i].repsCompleted = 5;
  }

  return exercise;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why getters behaves as such?

Comment: That's the whole point of getters. When you access the property, it runs the getter instead of just returning value of the property normally.

Comment: @Hirvesh getters are executed each time you lookup that propery

Comment: @Hirvesh I guess you thought it's only used the first time to initialize the value, but that's not how it works.

Comment: @Hirvesh Getters and setters allow you to totally override the way a property is implemented.

Comment: @Barmar my idea was to access sets using a braket-less syntax - barbellSquat.sets[0].repsCompleted 

So now I have to do barbellSquat.sets()[0].repsCompleted ?

Comment: No, you access it the same way as before, you just don't define the getter.

Comment: I've added more details to the answer.

Comment: thank you @Barmar, I just came to the same conclusion. Very helpful from you! :)